# При наведении на один блок, менялось положение других блоков(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Всем доброго времени суток.
Задача сделать так, чтобы при наведении на одну плитку, менялось положение других с помощью scale, проблема в том что если навести на нечетную плиту(текстodd), потом навести на другую нечетную то анимация не происходит, пока не наведу на четную, так же происходит и с четными плитками.
А нужно что-бы при наведении на каждую, они менялись согласно анимации.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет что я не так сделал?
Вот код https://jsfiddle.net/a7jwk8gr/5/

```js
let oddLinkMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.odd-link');
let evenLinkMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".even-link");

function hoverMenu() {
  let menuLinkActive = document.querySelector('_active');
  if (menuLinkActive) {
    menuLinkActive.classList.remove('_active');
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < oddLinkMenu.length; i++) {
    oddLinkMenu[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
      evenLinkMenu.forEach((evenLinkMenu) => evenLinkMenu.classList.add("_active"));
    });
    oddLinkMenu[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
      evenLinkMenu.forEach((evenLinkMenu) => evenLinkMenu.classList.remove("_active"));
    });
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < evenLinkMenu.length; i++) {
    evenLinkMenu[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
      oddLinkMenu.forEach((oddLinkMenu) => oddLinkMenu.classList.add("_active"));
    });
    evenLinkMenu[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
      oddLinkMenu.forEach((oddLinkMenu) => oddLinkMenu.classList.remove("_active"));
    });
  }
}

hoverMenu();
```

```css
.center-menu__column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.center-menu__column-2 {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.center-menu__block {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.center-menu__block-2 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.center-menu__block-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 189px;
}

.center-menu__subblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.center-menu__subblock-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 491px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.center-menu__subblock-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 491px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.center-menu__link-1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #161616;
  flex: 1 1 380px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 43px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 49px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #ccba96;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 31px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 49px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #b99c63;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  /*
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0px 0px 40px 5px rgba(185, 156, 99, 0.5);
  }
  */
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 37px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.center-menu__link-4 span {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #b99c63;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-4 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 43px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccba96;
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-5 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 37px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-6 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccba96;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 191px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-6 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-7 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-7 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 43px;
  }
}

.even-link._active {
  animation: link-hover-even 1s linear;
}

.odd-link._active {
  animation: link-hover-odd 1s linear;
}

@keyframes link-hover-even {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes link-hover-odd {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.98);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__center center-menu">
  <div class="center-menu__column">
    <div class="center-menu__link-1 odd-link">Текстodd</div>
    <div class="center-menu__block">
      <a href="" class="center-menu__link-2 even-link">Текст</a>
      <a href="" class="center-menu__link-3 odd-link">Текстodd</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-menu__column-2">
    <div class="center-menu__block-2">
      <div class="center-menu__block-3">
        <a href="" class="center-menu__link-4 even-link"><span>Текст</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="center-menu__subblock">
        <div class="center-menu__subblock-1">
          <a href="" class="center-menu__link-5 odd-link">Текстodd</a>
          <a href="" class="center-menu__link-6 even-link">Текст</a>
        </div>
        <div class="center-menu__subblock-2">
          <a href="" class="center-menu__link-7 odd-link">Текстodd</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @freestyle_HD, это единоразовые биндинги слушателей на элементы. Функция `hoverMenu` вызывается единожды. Да, на нативном JS это выглядит страшнее чем это можно было бы через тот же jQuery.

Comment: Из экспериментов помогло отсрочивать добавление класса до следующего тика с помощью функции `setTimeout`. Например: `evenLinkMenu.forEach((evenLinkMenu) => setTimeout(() => evenLinkMenu.classList.add("_active")));`. Предположу, что браузер не успевает перезапустить анимации во время "мигания" классов `_active` и ему необходимо _выжидать паузу_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анимацию надо бы другую чуток, не совсем правильная, но у вас вопрос и не с ней связан был.

```js
let oddLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.odd-link');
let evenLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".even-link");
let allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='center-menu__link-']");


function hoverMenu(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('even-link')) {
    evenLinks.forEach((evLink) => evLink.classList.add("_active"));
  }
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('odd-link')) {
    oddLinks.forEach((oddLink) => oddLink.classList.add("_active"));
  }
}

allLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseenter", hoverMenu);
  link.addEventListener("animationend", () => link.classList.remove("_active"));
})
```

```css
.center-menu__column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.center-menu__column-2 {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.center-menu__block {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.center-menu__block-2 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.center-menu__block-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 189px;
}

.center-menu__subblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.center-menu__subblock-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 491px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.center-menu__subblock-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 491px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.center-menu__link-1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #161616;
  flex: 1 1 380px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 43px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 49px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #ccba96;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 31px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 49px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #b99c63;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  /*
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0px 0px 40px 5px rgba(185, 156, 99, 0.5);
  }
  */
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 37px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.center-menu__link-4 span {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #b99c63;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-4 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 43px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccba96;
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-5 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 37px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-6 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccba96;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 191px;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-6 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
  }
}

.center-menu__link-7 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #161616;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .center-menu__link-7 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 43px;
  }
}

.even-link._active {
  animation: link-hover-even 1s linear;
  color: red;
}

.odd-link._active {
  animation: link-hover-odd 1s linear;
  color: blue;
}

@keyframes link-hover-even {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes link-hover-odd {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__center center-menu">
  <div class="center-menu__column">
    <div class="center-menu__link-1 odd-link">Текстodd</div>
    <div class="center-menu__block">
      <a href="" class="center-menu__link-2 even-link">Текст</a>
      <a href="" class="center-menu__link-3 odd-link">Текстodd</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-menu__column-2">
    <div class="center-menu__block-2">
      <div class="center-menu__block-3">
        <a href="" class="center-menu__link-4 even-link"><span>Текст</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="center-menu__subblock">
        <div class="center-menu__subblock-1">
          <a href="" class="center-menu__link-5 odd-link">Текстodd</a>
          <a href="" class="center-menu__link-6 even-link">Текст</a>
        </div>
        <div class="center-menu__subblock-2">
          <a href="" class="center-menu__link-7 odd-link">Текстodd</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```